# Imported object is messed up when zoomed out

Tags: mesh, import

I've imported .obj file (from 3ds Max) to Blender. If I zoom in, the rocks and the sand appears to intersect nicely.

[image]

However, if I zoom out, the intersection appears to be highly messed up.

[image]

Is there any way to make the intersection appear good even when I'm zoomed out?

Comment: Maybe not an answer, but just have a quick check of the camera's max and min clipping distances, to make sure they enclose the scene max and min distances reasonably closely (within orders of 10)

Comment: The clip start number was set to 0.01. Setting it to 10 helped to solve the issue. Thanks!